# Anguilla Framework in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, cme, gui-extensions

Do you know if exists something similar to Anguilla Framework for using it in Experiencie Manager (XPM)? I have used the same Anguilla commands that I use in Content Manager and they have not worked.

Comment: Can you edit your question and supply some more details, like what have you exactly tried and what is not working etc.?

Comment: Hi, i'm developing and extension to create a component dinamically. For this propose I use anguilla commands like "$display".could you tell me is there is any command like this for XPM?

Comment: Please EDIT your quesion and provide the additional details in there (don't use the comments where space is limited etc.). Those details should include information about what you are exactly trying to do, like where are you trying to use `$display` in XPM, how is your Editor/Model configured etc. etc.

Comment: `$display` is available in XPM by the way, but it depends on where you are trying to use it. It will be there in the Ribbon Bar, and in the popup windows of XPM for example. But you won't find it on the webpage, since that is not a "window" (or display) controlled by XMP, it is a webpage from the staging site (there are a few limited `Tridion` objects available in there, loaded from the bootstrap script, which supply the overlays required for editing).

Answer (score 4):

Basically the Anguilla Framework is for the CME and for XPM, see also my answer here: [How to integrate my custom button into Experience Manager](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-to-integrate-my-custom-button-into-experience-manager/3098#3098)

What you need to do is specify in your Editor and/or Model extension configuration whether you are extending something in the CMe or in XPM (which is called `SiteEdit` in the configuration. You can also have your extension apply to both, by specifying both in the configuration XML, the nodes you are looking for are:

```
...
<extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
        <ext:editorextension target="CME">
            ...
            <!-- add your extension nodes for the CME here -->
            ...
        </ext:editorextension>
        <ext:editorextension target="SiteEdit">
            ...
            <!-- add your extension nodes for XPM here -->
            ...
        </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>
    ...
</extensions>
...
```

*NOTE: If you edit your question and provide a little more detail about your specific example, I can update my answer with a more specific example...*